# converting a conic equation to standard form.

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections

original equation: $1.1x^2-1.3xy+y^2-2.9x-1.9y = 0$

I found the angle of rotation to be 47.2 by finding the arccot of b/a-c

the x' and y' conversions:

$x = x'cos(47.2) - y'sin(47.2)$

$y = x'sin(47.2) + y'cos(47.2)$

the final equation once simplified is:

$.3981x^2+.0001xy-3.3643x + 1.7014y^2+.8368y = 0$

my question is how I would go about converting this into standard form so I can graph the elipsis on the rotated axis.

Comment: The expression given is not an equation;  is it equal to zero?

Comment: I suggest translating before rotating to eliminate the linear terms.

Comment: @DJohnM yes, fixed

Answer (score 1):

Since these are approximated values, forget the $.0001xy$ part. Then$$.3981x^2-3.3643x=(.630952x-2.66605)^2-7.10783$$and$$1.7014y^2+.8368y=(1.30438y+.320766)^2-.102891.$$

Comment: could you explain how it would be done including the xy for my future reference?

Comment: @SergeiLevashov I am confused by your question. It's you who made the computations needed to eliminate the $xy$ part and now you are asking me how to do them. Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: You said to ignore .0001xy. How would I solve it if it was a larger number that couldn't be ignored?

Comment: @SergeiLevashov But the whole point of finding that angle of $47.2^\circ$ that you mentioned is to eliminate the $xy$ term. If, in the end, you got a large number, that would mean that there was an error in the computations.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. xy is what controls rotation then I assume? So separating the angle of rotation and finding the new problem allows for it to be graphed on the new axis.

Comment: @SergeiLevashov I would state this way: the term $xy$ is what prevents the axis of the ellipsis from being parallel to the ordinary axis. So, you rotate the ellipsis in order to elliminate that problem.

Comment: How did you get 2.66605 inside of the square? Also how would I graph the eclipse with these two equations? Plug in decimals or radians?

Comment: @SergeiLevashov $-2.66605=\frac{-3.3643}{2\times.630952}$. For the rest, see whatever book you used to find the angle.

Answer (score 1):

I would proceed as follows:

The discriminant $(-1.3)^2-4(1.1)(1.0)=-2.71\lt0$, so this is an ellipse. Its center can be found by differentiating and setting the partial derivatives to zero: $$\begin{align}2.2x-1.3y-2.9 &= 0 \\ -1.3x+2.0y-1.9 &= 0\end{align}$$ with solution $x=3.05166$, $y=2.93358$. So, first translate the origin to this point by making the substitution $x\mapsto x'+3.05166$, $y\mapsto y'+2.93358$, producing the transformed equation $$1.1 x'^2-1.3 x'y'+y'^2-7.21181=0.$$ You can save yourself some work by taking advantage of the fact that a translation doesn’t affect the second-degree terms and replaces the constant term with the value obtained by plugging the coordinates of the translation vector into the left-hand side of the equation; translating to the center of the ellipse eliminates the linear terms.

Now, you can apply your rotation to eliminate the cross term. This will leave the constant term unchanged, leaving the last step of normalizing the coefficients.